# UAA: add user to group when there is duplicate user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, cloudfoundry-uaa

I'm working with UAA from cloudfoundry. there are two users with same email: saml and uaa. when i do `get`, uaac ask me to choose user:

```
uaac user get xxx@yyy.com
Select an origin:
1. uaa
2. SAML
Select user:
```

to avoid the question i can also do this:

```
uaac user get xxx@yyy.com --origin=uaa
```

and when i do

```
uaac member add scim.read xxx@yyy.com
```

i got:

```
RuntimeError: not all users found, none added
```

and i can't do

```
uaac member add scim.read xxx@yyy.com --origin=uaa
```

so how can i add one specific user to UAA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way i found was to use `uaac curl`:

> uaac curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"value":"xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx","origin":"uaa","type":"USER"}' /Groups/yyyy-yyy-yyy-yyy-yyyy/members

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create account--and it seems like you are, given you're trying to "add" a user to the UAA origin--you should use `uaac user add` instead of `uaac member add`